# How do I nest JS media query within the sticky navbar function(onscroll) and onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So there's a way to use media query on JavaScript, but it seems it only works when the window gets resized, but it doesn't work well when it's nested within the `onscroll` and `onclick` functions.

Try to run this code and resize the window, it works but try to set the width of your browser window to **768px**, it works but when you start scrolling, it starts to revert back to tablet media query which set the elements color to the tablet mode instead of desktop mode. Even resizing the window, it's not working well when it's nested within a function. How do I fix this? Try to run this in **Full Page** to be able to resize the window

```js
window.onscroll = function() {stickynavbar();}

var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
var myBtn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

var desktop = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
var tablet = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)");

function stickynavbar() {

  function element1Query(desktop){
      if (desktop.matches){
          element1.style.background = "darkred";
      }
      else{
          element1.style.background = "black";
      }
  }
  element1Query(desktop);
  desktop.addListener(element1Query);

  function element1TQuery(tablet){
      if (tablet.matches){
          element1.style.background = "darkblue";
      }
      else{
          element1.style.background = "black";
      }
  }
  element1TQuery(tablet);
  tablet.addListener(element1TQuery);

  function element2Query(desktop){
      if (desktop.matches){
          element2.style.background = "darkgreen";
      }
      else{
          element2.style.background = "gray";
      }
  }
  element2Query(desktop);
  desktop.addListener(element2Query);

  function element2TQuery(tablet){
      if (tablet.matches){
          element2.style.background = "yellow";
      }
      else{
          element2.style.background = "gray";
      }
  }

  element2TQuery(tablet);
  tablet.addListener(element2TQuery);
}
```

```css
.element1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1000px;
        background: black;
    }
    .element2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1000px;
        background: gray;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="element1" id="element1"></div>
<div class="element2" id="element2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want like this?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {stickynavbar();}

var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
var element2 = document.getElementById("element2");
var myBtn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];

var desktop = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)");
var tablet = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)");

function stickynavbar() {

  function element1Query(desktop){
      if (desktop.matches){
          element1.style.background = "darkred";
      }
      else{
          element1.style.background = "black";
      }
  }
  element1Query(desktop);
  desktop.addListener(element1Query);

  function element1TQuery(tablet){
      if (tablet.matches){
          element1.style.background = "darkblue";
      }
      else{
          element1.style.background = "black";
      }
  }
  element1TQuery(tablet);
  tablet.addListener(element1TQuery);

  function element2Query(desktop){
      if (desktop.matches){
          element2.style.background = "darkgreen";
      }
      else{
          element2.style.background = "gray";
      }
  }
  element2Query(desktop);
  desktop.addListener(element2Query);

  function element2TQuery(tablet){
      if (tablet.matches){
          element2.style.background = "yellow";
      }
      else{
          element2.style.background = "gray";
      }
  }

  element2TQuery(tablet);
  tablet.addListener(element2TQuery);
}
```

```css
.element1{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1000px;
        background: black;
    }
    .element2{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 50%;
        height: 1000px;
        background: gray;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="element1" id="element1"></div>
<div class="element2" id="element2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to resize the width of your browser window to 768px, it'll start to change to green and blue, but start scrolling, it'll be reverted back to black and gray. How do I prevent this?

Comment: What I want is, when you resize the browser window to 768px(desktop) it'll change the first(left side) element's color to darkred , 600px(tablet) to darkblue, and mobile to yellow which is the `else` statement. The issue here is, when you resize the browser to 768px, it'll change the color(which means it works), **but** once you scroll down, the color of the element changes to darkblue, which means it's tablet's size instead of darkred(desktop) even though it's on 768px size of the window.